# Chrome dev-tools - Changing a local variable on break-point is not evaluated in next step over

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using chrome 59 (issue was also reproduced in chrome 62).
When i'm stopping on a certain if-condition break-point,
i'm trying to change a local variable value before doing the next step-over (F10), even though the change was updated (i'm seeing the updated value in console), the if-condition still considering the previous (original) value for some reason.
It looks like after the change, the variable is not re-evaluated.

Is someone familiar with this problem? i'm not sure if this is a browser bug or some chrome's settings configuration.

Here's a sample for reproduce:

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>JavaScript chrome issue test</h2>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Stop on debug</button>
        <script src="myScript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**myScript.js:**

```
function myFunction() {
    let test = 'sss';
    if (test) { // stop here in debug, and change test var to null in the console.
        console.log ('yes');
    } else {
        console.log ('no');
    }
}
```

Here's also a link for reproduce:
http://jsfiddle.net/Bnuy7/2582/

Notice: if you'll use debugger it will work properly, you need to break on the if-condition line without using 'debugger' command.

Will glad for any assistance with this.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reproducible code, it really helps me be able to help you. Yeah, I reproduced it and this looks like a bug (or at least unintuitive behavior). Looks like you filed a bug already... https://crbug.com/789241